# Alamofire publish decodable

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I have a HTTP request to my server like this.

```
func loginUser( username: String, password: String )->AnyPublisher<UserModel, Error>{

    let url = URL( string: "\(Credentials.BASE_URL)auth/login")!
    let userSignInModel = SignInModel(username: username, password: password)
    
    return AF.request(url,
                      method: .post,
                      parameters: userSignInModel,
                      encoder: JSONParameterEncoder.default)
        .validate()
        .publishDecodable(type: UserModel.self)
        .value()
        .mapError{$0 as Error}
        .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

and get response like this

```
    self.dataManager.loginUser(username: self.logInUsername, password: self.logInPassword)
        .sink { (response) in
            print( response )
            switch response {
                case .failure( let error ):
                    self.createAlert(with: error.localizedDescription,
                                     for: .loginAlert,
                                     responseCode: error.asAFError?.responseCode)
                case .finished:
                    break
            }
        } receiveValue: { (userModel) in                
            self.token = userModel.token
            self.userID = userModel.user.id
        }.store(in: &cancellableSet)
```

but the problem is that I am not able to get error message from the server, how it can be done?

Comment: What do you mean by error messages from the server? You mean there's an alternative body when requests fail and you want to parse those failures?

Comment: yes for example the error is smth like status, message and I want to fetch it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several different approaches to parsing responses which return success or response values. Perhaps the simplest is to map any initial failures to your own error type which parses the information you need. For example, given this error type:

```swift
struct NetworkError: Error {
  let initialError: AFError
  let backendError: BackendError?
}
```

Where `BackendError` encapsulates the information returned from the backend. Then you can map the response from Alamofire.

```swift
AF.request(url,
           method: .post,
           parameters: userSignInModel)
    .validate()
    .publishDecodable(type: UserModel.self)
    .map { response in
        response.mapError { error in
            // Check to see if it's an error that should have backend info.
            // Assuming it is, parse the BackendError.
            let backendError = response.data.flatMap { try? JSONDecoder().decode(BackendError.self, from: $0) }
            return NetworkError(initialError: error, backendError: backendError)
        }
    }
```

Other alternatives include an `enum`-based response type that separates your success and failures, or your own response serializer which does the error parsing internally.